# Python argparse ignore unrecognised arguments

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

Optparse, the old version just ignores all unrecognised arguments and carries on.  In most situations, this isn't ideal and was changed in argparse.  But there are a few situations where you want to ignore any unrecognised arguments and parse the ones you've specified.

For example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', dest="foo")
parser.parse_args()

$python myscript.py --foo 1 --bar 2
error: unrecognized arguments: --bar
```

Is there anyway to override this?

Comment: Very handy if you're writing a wrapper to another program, and you want to capture and modify a few arguments, but pass the rest on!

Answer (score 525, accepted):

Replace

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

with

```
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

For example,

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args(['--foo', 'BAR', 'spam'])
print(args)
# Namespace(foo='BAR')
print(unknown)
# ['spam']
```

Comment: +1 - didn't knew there was some thing like `parse_known_args`

Comment: Nor did I!  I even missed it in the docs http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#partial-parsing.  Thanks

Comment: This came up when trying to use nosetest with parseargs (it refused to allow nosetest args to be used) the reason was because I was doing `parser.parse_args(None)` rather than `parser.parse_args([])` in my tests.

Comment: FWIW, using `parse_known_args` rather than `parse_args` enables the use of `ArgumentParser` in code within the scope of `if __name__ == 'main':` (a condition that is `True` for all cells in an IPython Notebook ... which I find greatly aids the development and testing code that I want to eventually migrate to a script invoked from a command line)

Comment: Oops: s/main/__main__/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with optional args that are "known" not being passed in.

Comment: Unfortunately `unknown` is simply array and there is no built-in way to convert to nice dictionary (as we don't know types). Alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37367814/207661.

Comment: Note that the `unknown` args can then be passed to another argparse instance, for example a [subparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers).

Comment: was able to work around a SystemExit condition with pytest -s -v with this solution

Answer (score 31):

You can puts the remaining parts into a new argument with `parser.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)` if you want to use them.

Comment: This works with `parse_args()` and doesn't require `parse_known_args()` (on Python 2.7).

Comment: Using argparse.REMAINDER seems to be fraught with long-standing bugs.  I certainly can't get it to work.  parse_known_args() is a good alternative.

Comment: Just ran into a long-standing REMAINDER bug today: https://bugs.python.org/issue17050

Answer (score 10):

Actually argparse does still "ignore" `_unrecognized_args`. As long as these "unrecognized" arguments **don't use the default prefix** you will hear no complaints from the parser.

Using @anutbu's configuration but with the standard `parse.parse_args()`, if we were to execute our program with the following arguments.

```
$ program --foo BAR a b +cd e
```

We will have this Namespaced data collection to work with.

```
Namespace(_unrecognized_args=['a', 'b', '+cd', 'e'], foo='BAR')
```

If we wanted the default prefix `-` ignored we could change the ArgumentParser and decide we are going to use a `+` for our "recognized" arguments instead.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prefix_chars='+')
parser.add_argument('+cd')
```

The same command will produce

```
Namespace(_unrecognized_args=['--foo', 'BAR', 'a', 'b'], cd='e')
```

Put that in your pipe and smoke it =)

nJoy!