# How can I call in2csv from a Python script?

Tags: python, csv, argparse

When I try calling the below code, I run into the following error: "You must specify a format when providing data via STDIN (pipe)."

```
subprocess.call(["in2csv", "--format", "xls", a_file, ">", output_file], shell=True)
```

I'm not sure why this is the case because I am telling it what the initial format is. I've looked at the [docs](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/in2csv.html), which isn't clear about the distinction between --format and -f.

**Update:** I've changed it to use argparse to simplify passing the arguments following [this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818146/python-argparse-ignore-unrecognised-arguments). I'm also using Popen as used [here](http://geeohspatial.blogspot.com/2013/04/batch-xls-or-xlsx-to-csv-with-python.html), which is apparently safer than using shell=true flag according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('in2csv')
parser.add_argument('--format')
parser.add_argument('xls')
parser.add_argument(a_file)
parser.add_argument(">")
parser.add_argument(output_file)
args = parser.parse_args()
print args
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

Comment: Let `cmd =["in2csv", "--format", "xls", "file.xls", ">", "file.csv"]`.  Then `subprocess.call( ' '.join(cmd), shell=True)`  should work. I am not sure why `subprocess.call( 'cmd, shell=True)` will not work.  I ran `in2csv -` and `in2csv --` from directly the command line and received the same error: `in2csv: error: You must specify a format when providing data via STDIN (pipe).`

Comment: @dermen can you recommend how to do it with argparse?

Comment: just a few suggestions `subprocess.Popen` can be used to pipe the output to a file using subprocess.PIPE as in eg. `subprocess.Popen([cmd],stdout=fd,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False)` and personally I dont think you need args parse as long as you are not passing parameters to the command line all you need is the correct string like `cmd = "in2csv --format xls {0}.format(a_file)"` Also please check the return from subprocess.Popen and make the call blocking to complete the command before exit

Comment: The code you posted is broken, and actually argparse is not what you need to answer your question.  To answer your question, pass a string instead of a list of strings (like I did in the comment above). As for why the error is being thrown, I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors like what you've seen are a symptom of the shell getting confused by the string passed in, for instance because of a space in a filename. It is indeed best to avoid using the shell when spawning processes from Python.

Instead of adding ">" and `output_file` as arguments, try redirecting the output using the [stdout](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) keyword argument, which takes a file that output will be written to.

Assuming:

- `a_file` is a string with the name of your input file, and
- `output_file` is a string with the name of your desired output file,

a working call might look like:

```
with open(output_file, 'wb') as of:
  subprocess.check_call(["in2csv", "--format", "xls", a_file],
                         stdout=of)
```

It's not necessary to use argparse here; it's meant for handling command lines coming in to your program, rather than going out from it.