# Handling argparse conflicts

Tags: python, argparse

If I import a Python [module](https://github.com/paulcalabro/api-kickstart/blob/master/examples/python/config.py) that is already using **argparse**, however, I would like to use **argparse** in my script as well ...how should I go about doing this?

I'm receiving a *unrecognized arguments* error when using the following code and invoking the script with a -t flag:

**Snippet:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

....
import conflicting_module
import argparse
...

#################################
# Step 0: Configure settings... #
#################################
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process command line options.')
parser.add_argument('--test', '-t')
```

**Error:**

```
 unrecognized arguments: -t foobar
```

Comment: Please show the full code and the full command line arguments you are passing to your script. You may find this to be useful: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to guard your **imported modules** with

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
```

against it running initialization code such as argument parsing on import. See  [What does `if __name__ == "__main__":` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

So, in your `conflicting_module` do

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process command line options in conflicting_module.py.')
    parser.add_argument('--conflicting', '-c')
    ...
```

instead of just creating the parser globally.

If the parsing in `conflicting_module` is a mandatory part of application configuration, consider using

```
args, rest = parser.parse_known_args()
```

in your main module and passing `rest` to `conflicting_module`, where you'd pass either `None` or `rest` to `parse_args`:

```
args = parser.parse_args(rest)
```

That is still a bit bad style and actually the classes and functions in `conflicting_module` would ideally receive parsed configuration arguments from your main module, which would be responsible for parsing them.

Comment: It looks like most the code is contained within the constructor. 
Even if I move line 39 into the constructor, it still produces the same effect.

https://github.com/paulcalabro/api-kickstart/blob/master/examples/python/config.py

Comment: I'm guessing you use `EdgeGridConfig` then. It will still add those arguments, and on line https://github.com/paulcalabro/api-kickstart/blob/master/examples/python/config.py#L60 attempt to parse them and fail.

Comment: @PaulCalabro to put it in other words: you're out of luck with this one.

Comment: Okay, I can workaround that. Just wanted to know if there was a Pythonic way to handle this kindof thing. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulCalabro Remove the argument parsing from `__init__`, make it a separate method to be called. Call it in your module guarded with the `if __name__ == '__main__':`, if you must. Allow the method to receive [unknown arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args)

Comment: Good idea! I'll give that  a try and post back. Ty!

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/47587545/5472444, simply using `args = parser.parse_args(args=[])` worked for me when dealing with the error `ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f` caused by the way ipython jupyter extension in vscode was running. Since the module with conflict was a 'silent' dependency I wasn't importing, it wasn't clear to me how I'd pass on `rest` as per the solution above.