# Accepting commandline options without a predefined list

Tags: python, python-3.x

As far as I can tell, both [`getopt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html) and [`optparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html) must be used with a pre-defined list of permitted commandline options. Is there a way to get them (or another option-parsing module I don't know about) to accept any option that starts with `-`?

Reason: I have a short python command line program that basically delegates to another module with an extended option API. I want to do a little bit of commandline processing in my program, and pass all unrecognized options to the delegate module. While I could hack it in pure python, I would prefer to rely on one of the standard modules. Both short and long options should be supported (`-o`, `--long-opt` and `--long-option=argument`), but obviously I don't expect to support the syntax `--long-option argument` for an unknown option.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818146/python-argparse-ignore-unrecognised-arguments

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Marked my question as a duplicate.