# argparse when using a REMAINDER

Tags: python

I create the following argument parser:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('name')
parser.add_argument('script')
parser.add_argument('--src', nargs='?')
```

When running `./script.py the_name the_script --src my_script.py`, all the arguments get their value "as expected".

Now, I add a remainder:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('name')
parser.add_argument('script')
parser.add_argument('--src', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
```

Now, running again `./script.py the_name the_script --src my_script.py`, argument `src` suddenly becomes `None`.

However, running `./script.py --src my_script.py the_name the_script --arg1 arg2 xyz` will set all arguments "as expected".

How can I achieve that my argument parser first wants to see the positional arguments `name` and `script`, then some known arguments like `--src` and then finally an arbitrary remainder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python argparse ignore unrecognised arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818146/python-argparse-ignore-unrecognised-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

```
parser.add_argument('args', nargs='+')
```

But then you have to always provide at least one `args` argument.

```
print parser.parse_args('--src 12 1 2 3 4'.split())
print parser.parse_args('1 2 --src 12 3 4'.split())
```

Output:

```
Namespace(args=['3', '4'], name='1', script='2', src='12')
Namespace(args=['3', '4'], name='1', script='2', src='12')
```

Doesn't work with `nargs='*'`, alas:

```
parser.add_argument('args', nargs='*')

print parser.parse_args('--src 12 1 2 3 4'.split())
print parser.parse_args('1 2 --src 12 3 4'.split())
```

Output:

```
Namespace(args=['3', '4'], name='1', script='2', src='12')
usage: argp.py [-h] [--src SRC] name script [args [args ...]]
argp.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 3 4
```

I.e. `--src 12 1 2 3 4` works but `1 2 --src 12 3 4` doesn't.

Comment: Tried it. Does not help. `src` is still `None`.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your question is very similar to the example used in the end of [section "15.4.3.3. nargs" in Python's official docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#nargs).

Seems like the answer to your problem is to put `--src` as the first parameter, before the positional ones.

I did the following and it seems to work:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--src')
parser.add_argument('name')
parser.add_argument('script')
parser.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
```

When I run the above script like using `./script.py --src=my_script.py the_name the_script 1 2 3` the result is, as expected:

```
name = the_name
script = the_script
src = my_script.py
args = ['1', '2', '3']
```

If I remove the --src like `./script.py the_name the_script 1 2 3` the result is:

```
name = the_name
script = the_script
src = None
args = ['1', '2', '3']`
```

Naturally I can keep the `--src` and omit the `1 2 3` parameters, thus if I run `./script.py --src=my_script.py the_name the_script` the result is:

```
name = the_name
script = the_script
src = my_script.py
args = []`
```

Which looks like what you'll expect.

Comment: I can't turn it into a positional argument because it is optional.

Comment: @Michael I updated my answer, please check if it meets your needs now.