# Python multiprocessing throws error with argparse and pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, pyinstaller, python-multiprocessing

In my project, I'm using argprse to pass arguments and somewhere in script I'm using multiprocessing to do rest of the calculations. Script is working fine if I call it from command prompt 
for ex.

"`python complete_script.py --arg1=xy --arg2=yz`" .

But after converting it to exe using Pyinstaller using command "pyinstaller --onefile complete_script.py" it throws

error

> " error: unrecognized arguments: --multiprocessing-fork 1448"

Any suggestions how could I make this work. Or any other alternative. My goal is to create an exe application which I can call in other system where Python is not installed.

Here are the details of my workstation:

```
Platform: Windows 10
Python : 2.7.13 <installed using Anaconda>
multiprocessing : 0.70a1
argparse:   1.1
```

---

Copied from comment:

```
def main():
     main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     < added up arguments here>
    all_inputs = main_parser.parse_args()
    wrap_function(all_inputs)


def wrap_function(all_inputs):
    <Some calculation here >
   distribute_function(<input array for multiprocessing>)

def distribute_function(<input array>):
    pool = Pool(process = cpu_count)
    jobs = [pool.apply_async(target_functions, args = (i,) for i in input_array)]
    pool.close()
```

Comment: I've had numerous issues using Anaconda distributions + pyinstaller. I'm not sure pyinstaller is tested against Anaconda. My advice, if you're going to freeze a python app, make your life easier and use canonical python, not third-party distributions

Comment: this was a really good solution for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818146/python-argparse-ignore-unrecognised-arguments use args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args() and it will quietly parse even with unknown args, and now multiprocessing works in pyinstaller just fine

Answer (score 23):

(A bit late but it can be useful for someone else in the future...)

I had the same problem, after some research I found [this multiprocessing pyInstaller recipe](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Multiprocessing) that states:

> When using the multiprocessing module, you must call
>
> `multiprocessing.freeze_support()`
>
> straight after the `if __name__ == '__main__':` line of the main module.
>
> Please read the [Python library manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support) about multiprocessing.freeze_support for more information.

Adding that line of code solved the problem for me.

Comment: Awesome answer, you saved my day.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `freeze_support()` is _only_ relevant on Windows. (This question is not tagged Windows, and while the OP mentions they _are_ using Windows, non-Windows users may find this question.)

Answer (score 0):

I may be explaining the obvious, but you don't give us much information to work with.

```
python complete_script.py --arg1=xy --arg2=yz
```

This sort of call tells me that your `parser` is setup to accept at least these 2 arguments, ones flagged with '--arg1' and '--arg2'.

The error tells me that this parser (or maybe some other) is also seeing this string:

```
--multiprocessing-fork 1448
```

Possibly generated by the multiprocessing code.  It would be good to see the `usage` part of the error, just to confirm which parser is complaining.

One of my first open source contributions to Python was to enhance the warnings about multiprocessing on Windows.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows

Is your parser protected by a `if __name__` block?  Should this particular parser be called when run in a fork?  You probably designed the parser to work when the program is called as a standalone script.  But when happens when it is imported?

Comment: This might useful information to work for: 

['code']
def main():
main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
< added up arguments here>
all_inputs = main_parser.parse_args()
wrap_function(all_inputs)


def wrap_function(all_inputs):
<Some calculation here >
distribute_function(<input array for multiprocessing>)

def distribute_function(<input array>):
pool = Pool(process = cpu_count)
jobs = [pool.apply_async(target_functions, args = (i,) for i in input_array)]
pool.close()
['code']

Comment: When is `main` called?  On import or only by a `is __name__...` block?

Comment: main() is called by  __name__ ==  '__main__'  block