# pandas-profiling issues with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, pandas, cx-freeze, pandas-profiling

I'm using `cx_freeze` to convert my Python app to Windows executable file. I am using `pandas-profiling` package in one of my scripts. When I run my exe file I get the following error:

```
    File "C:\Users\Ronnie\python3.6\Lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pandas_profiling.templates as templates
  File "C:\Users\Ronnie\python3.6\Lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\templates.py", line 64, in <module>
    row_templates_dict = {'NUM': template('row_num'),
  File "C:\Users\Ronnie\python3.6\Lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\templates.py", line 60, in template
    return jinja2_env.get_template(templates[template_name], globals=globals)
  File "C:\Users\Ronnie\python3.6\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Users\Ronnie\python3.6\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Users\Ronnie\python3.6\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "C:\Users\Ronnie\python3.6\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 234, in get_source
    if not self.provider.has_resource(p):
  File "C:\Users\Ronnie\python3.6\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1396, in has_resource
    return self._has(self._fn(self.module_path, resource_name))
  File "C:\Users\Ronnie\python3.6\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1449, in _has
    "Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type"
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
```

And If I place the `pandas-profiling` in the same directory as the exe file and then run it, I get the following error:

```
 error: unrecognized arguments: --multiprocessing-fork 1448
```

While looking for a solution to the multiprocessing error, I found out that `pandas-profiling` is using `multiprocessing` in one of its scripts and there needs to be `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` call in that module but I can't figure out where to add this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support) of `multiprocessing.freeze_support()`:

> One needs to call this function straight after the `if __name__ == '__main__'` line of the main module. For example:
>
> ```
> from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
>
> def f():
>       print('hello world!')
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     freeze_support()
>     Process(target=f).start()
> ```

So you need to call this function straight after the `if __name__ == '__main__'` line of your script which uses `pandas-profiling`.

If you don't have such a line in your script: add this line before the first top-level code line of you script and indent the whole top-level code of your script so that it belongs to the `if` block. See [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/8516269)

See also [Python multiprocessing throws error with argparse and pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46335842/8516269) and [where to put freeze_support() in a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24374288/8516269)