# ConfigArgParse throwing unrecognized arguments with default config.ini

Tags: python, argparse

as far as I understood, with [ConfigArgParse](https://pypi.org/project/ConfigArgParse/), I can set the very main config in a config.ini file of my program and make some of those choices available via command line. However, when I set my config.ini file as default in the constructor, I get the following error:

```
main.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --input_base data
```

where --input_base is the only configuration not included in my parser as can be seen in the following:

```
parser = ArgParser(default_config_files=['config.ini'])
parser.add_argument('-out', '--output_base', type=str, help='xyz')
parser.add_argument('--amount', type=int, help='xyz')
parser.add_argument('--num_jobs', help='xyz')
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, help='xyz')
parser.add_argument('--queue_size', type=int, help='xyz')
parser.add_argument('--kind', choices={'long', 'short', 'both'}, help='xyz')
parser.add_argument('--level', choices={'DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL'}, help='xyz')
config = parser.parse_args()
```

Only using config.ini works fine but because of usability I have to include command line args as well.

Thanks for your help. Appreciate it!

Comment: What's your command line?  I don't know what `ConfigArgParse` adds to `argparse`, but evidently the 'unrecognized arguments' are in the `sys.argv` list that your parser is trying to parse.  Make sure you understand why.

Comment: Could you maybe give me a little more info what you mean?

the unknown arguments come from the `config.ini` file mentioned in the first line with `parser = ...`. However, I did not know how to access those correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Try change last line to:

```
config, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

This will parse only known arguments (ignoring every unknown).

as in this question: [Python argparse ignore unrecognised arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818146/python-argparse-ignore-unrecognised-arguments)

Comment: Great, thank you! I think this is what I was looking for. Is there anyway to access those arguments in an elegant way like I can do it with those in `config` with `config.arg`?

PS: sorry for the late reply, I was caught up with something else

Comment: unknown is just simple list of strings. You can use it this way, for example: 
`if '--unknown' in unknown:`. But there is no other way, because processing possible only for known args (which provides rules, how to process arguments)