# How to make a python script be stringent on checking parameters passed in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have the following script which simply parses arguments passed in commandline

```
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My test script')
    parser.add_argument('-somearg', dest='somearg', type=str, required=True, help='Help yourself')
    parser.add_argument("-somemorearg", dest='somemorearg', action='store_true', help='Help yourself')   # Treated as boolean if passed in
    parser.add_argument("-somemoreargagain", dest='somemoreargagain', action='store_true', help='Help yourself') # Treated as boolean if passed in
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print('Your input was:         ' + args.somearg)
    if args.somemorearg == True:
        print('Second parameter is true: ')
    if args.somemoreargagain == True:
        print('Second parameter is true: ')
```

Following is the way I call the script which works:

```
python my_script.py -somearg xyz -somemorearg -somemoreargagain
```

Above is great!
**But** if I call my script with a slight typo like below, that works as well? That is strange behaviour from python! Note that in the below call, I am missing the `n` in last parameter which should be `somemoreargagain`

```
python my_script.py -somearg xyz -somemorearg -somemoreargagai
```

Is above behaviour default in python as it looks like? I want to make the script stringent in parameter checks.

**How can I make the script throw an error if parameters passed in dont match accurately?** I want my script to only accept `-somearg`, `-somemorearg` and `-somemorearg`

I am using Python 3+

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818146/python-argparse-ignore-unrecognised-arguments

Comment: Please note my question is "How can I make the script throw an error if the criteria does not match?"

Comment: `allow_abbrev` parameter was added recently to give you control over its handing of abbreviations.  But you could also choose argument flags that are sufficiently different (and short) that this kind of error is impossible.  Your lazy users will thank you for it.

Answer (score 2):

using partial argument names works with argparse as long as it is long enough to be unique for only one parameter. the same wouldn't work if you typed `python my_script.py -somearg xyz -somemorear` since `-somemorear` would be an ambiguous name for 2 parameters

Comment: This informative. Is there a standard way to avoid this behaviour or I should manually check by comparing each "known argument" with a string value of what I expect?

Comment: that's just how argparse works, you can check the docs for any way to disable it

Comment: Is it possible to get what was passed into the script by doing an args.somearg.something? Its quite uncool of python to not allow me to change default behaviour

Comment: apparently you can pass `allow_abbrev=False` to the argparse constructor to disable this feature, took me less than 30 seconds to find in the docs