# python mrjob: ignore unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, argparse, mrjob

Normally, if I want to define a command-line option for [mrjob](https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/job.html#command-line-options), I have to do like this:

```py
class Calculate(MRJob):
    def configure_args(self):
        super(Calculate, self).configure_args()
        self.add_passthru_arg("-t", "--time", help="output folder for time")
```

When I want to use the argument, I just need to call `self.options.time` but it only works inside that class.

I want to track the time of the `mrjob` and write the time into the `json` file like this `cal.py`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import json
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-t", "--time", help = "Output file")
args = parser.parse_args()

class Calculate(MRJob):
    ...

start_time = datetime.now()
Calculate.run()
execute_time = (datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds()

data = {}
data["step1"] = execute_time
with open(args.time+'/time.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

When I run with this command:

```
python cal.py data/input/input.txt --output data/output --time data/output
```

I got this error:

```
usage: cal.py [-h] [-t TIME]
cal.py: error: unrecognized arguments: data/input/input.txt --output data/output
```

Then I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12818237/9500955) about using `parse_known_args()` and I tried it:

```
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

Now, I got a new error. I believe this is from `mrjob` because I did remove the `argparse` and run the same command, it returns exactly like this:

```
usage: cal.py [options] [input files]
cal.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --time data/output
```

How can I define an argument without affecting the `mrjob` class?

Comment: If `mrjob` has its own parser, coordinating commandline arguments is tricky.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah that right, that why I have to define the arguments again inside the `mrjob` class for it to ignore the `argparse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround solution but I hope there will be a better way of doing this.

I have to define the argument again inside the `mrjob` class so it can recognize it:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import json
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-t", "--time", help = "Output file")
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()

class Calculate(MRJob):
    def configure_args(self):
        super(Calculate, self).configure_args()
        self.add_passthru_arg("-t", "--time", help="output folder for time")

start_time = datetime.now()
Calculate.run()
execute_time = (datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds()

data = {}
data["step1"] = execute_time
with open(args.time+'/time.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

And run with this command:

```
python cal.py data/input/input.txt --output data/output --time data/output
```