# Pass a specific argument in python and ignore the rest

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I have a simple code that passes arguments in python as below

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Processing data')
parser.add_argument("-number" , required=True)
args = parser_args()

print('Hi your number is: ' + args.number)
```

so if I do `python main.py -number 1234`
it will print it for me.

What I want to do is if I add any other arguments like
`python main.py -blah -number 1234`
I want to get the same result as before but right now it is showing me an error saying 'unrecognized arguments: -blah'

Comment: @Verthais I imagine they want to ignore everything else, as the post title says.

Comment: @Peter Wood like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818146/python-argparse-ignore-unrecognised-arguments ?

Comment: @PeterWood Yes I just found that too. Thank you!