# Argparse: Ignore dashes in unknown arguments or collect values (potentially starting with dashes) until the next known command

Tags: python, argparse

I have a Python script that will later call multiple Bash scripts with `supprocess.run`. When calling the Python script, the user should be able to specify lists of arguments (some of which might start with hyphens) for the Bash scripts like

```
python script.py \
    --bash-args1 --param1 val1 --param2 val2 \
    --bash-args2 bla --param3 val3 --blu
```

Argparse should parse this into `Namespace(bash_args1=['--param1', 'val1', '--param2', 'val2'], bash_args2=['bla', '--param3', 'val3', '--blu'])`. Is there a canonical way of achieving this? I cannot use `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER` or `parser.parse_known_args` because I need to collect the arguments for more than one Bash script and a simple `nargs='+'` will fail if the secondary arguments start with dashes.

I guess I would need one of the following:

- Either something similar to `REMAINDER` that causes argparse to collect all strings up to the next known argument
- an option that tells argparse to ignore dashes in unknown arguments when using `nargs='+'`.

Comment: It is not possible to make the arguments of bash scripts be strings?
```python
python script.py \
    --bash-args1 '--param1 val1 --param2 --val2' \
    --bash-args2 'bla --param3 val3 --blu'
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing so far, but then the user needs to quote the arguments and I need to split the strings before passing them to `subprocess.run`. It works, but it's not as clean as I'd like it to be

Comment: that's a poor fit for `argparse`.

Comment: @hpaulj, why? It would only need an extra option to ignore the prefix char in unrecognized arguments and this would give argparse a lot more flexibility for using it in wrapper scripts.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12818237/18419414) could help you, just get the unknown arguments and make each `--bash-args1` a `subparser`

Comment: @Brinfer, how would you implement such behaviour with subparsers? AFAIK they are invoked based on the value of the first positional argument. How can one use multiple subparsers for one list of arguments?

Comment: Error on my part, you can not call several subcommands at the same time, it would not be the best solution.

Comment: `argparse` does not have an option to ignore unrecognized flag strings.  Such behavior has been discussed extensively on the bug/issues tracker and closed, https://bugs.python.org/issue9334

Comment: That's a shame, but thanks for the added context, @hpaulj!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For posterity:

There are a few ways of working around this limitation of `argparse`. I wrapped one up and [published it on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/argpass/). You can use it just like `argparse`. The only difference is that there is an extra option you can supply as `nargs` parameter in `add_argument`. When this option is used, the parser collects all unknown arguments (regardless of whether they start with a hyphen or not) until the next known argument. For more info check out the [repo on github](https://github.com/julibeg/argpass).